# Reverse order of rows

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a simple code to fully reverse / mirror the order of rows in an Excel spreadsheet?
This is different from using the Sort function (for example, UsedRange.Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlDescending) given Sort will keep the same order of appearance for entries that are linked to the same the same date.
Thank you!

Comment: This is not a programming service. Please show us what you have tried this far and also please follow the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Add a new column with an incrementing number (autofill will do this for you) then sort descending on that column.

Comment: Use the sequence function and index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reverse Rows

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TESTreverseRows()
    reverseRows ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
End Sub

Sub reverseRows(ByRef rng As Range)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            Dim Data As Variant: Data = rng.Value
            Dim r As Long: r = UBound(Data, 1)
            Dim c As Long: c = UBound(Data, 2)
            Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To r, 1 To c)
            Dim i As Long
            Dim j As Long
            For i = 1 To r
                For j = 1 To c
                    Result(r, j) = Data(i, j)
                Next j
                r = r - 1
            Next i
            rng.Value = Result
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```